# react-native Could not install the app on the device

Tags: android, react-native

hi i am starting with react-native on windows and I built my first project but when i run it with

```
react-native run-andoird
```

it gives me this

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'albums'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
 > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
 Required by:
     project :
  > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
           > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out: connect

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --
 debug option to get more log output.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 22s
  Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
  Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
  set up your Android development environment:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

please help me

Comment: Which gradle version are you using?

Comment: gradle version 4.1

Comment: Did you try connecting to the URL with something like telnet to see if it's accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as your username and profile info suggests, you are from Iran. in that case, always always always run react-native with your vpn turned ON.

react-native tries to download necessary packages and tools when running the run-android command, but lots of repositories return 403 codes. that's the reason you are getting the errors.

Comment: i tried with hot spot shield , psipon3  and avira and still doesnt work

Comment: you sure the VPN was working? the error says there was an error accessing this URL: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom. try and load it in your browser and if it continues loading without showing any results, then you need to change the vpn.